# Date to String in 'social' format

Tags: java, date, date-format

I am trying to achieve let’s say ‘social’ date format. I already have a solution, but it feels like a better one should exist. Why social and what do I mean:

If we look into Facebook time stamps of the posts we can distinguish between next options:

1. X seconds ago
2. X minutes ago
3. X hours ago
4. Yesterday at 11:07 am
5. Friday at 9:36 pm
6. May 5 at 5:00 pm
7. November 20 at 9:05 pm, 2012

I made next visual timeline for better explanation:
[image]

**For example:** 
If the current time is: 
*5:33 pm, 20 sec Wednesday* 
The social post happened between: *00:00 am Tuesday* <--> *5:33 pm, 20 sec Tuesday*, 
then the date format should be like: **Yesterday at 11:07 am**.

**Solution I have**:
I check each option (7 in count) and return 'social' date string.

This is how I check for **option 1**:

```
Date postDate = getPostDate();
Date nowDate = getNowDate();

// check passed seconds
int passedSeconds = getPassedSeconds(postDate, nowDate);
if (passedSeconds < 60)
{
    return passedSeconds + " seconds ago";
}
```

This is how I check for **option 4**:

```
// check yesterday
Date startYesterdayDate = getZeroDayBeforeDays(nowDate, 1);
int compare = compare(startYesterdayDate, postDate);

// if postDate comes after startYesterdayDate
if (compare == -1)
{
    return "Yesterday at " + getString(postDate, "HH:mma");
}
```

I check other options in the same manner.

Some methods I use in my if statements above:

```
public static String getString(Date date, String format)
{
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
    String s = formatter.format(date);
    return s;
}

/**
 * For example: today - 1 day
 * 
 * @param date
 * @param numOfMinusDays
 * @return
 */
public static Date getDateMinusDays(Date date, int numOfMinusDays)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (0 - numOfMinusDays));
    return calendar.getTime();
}

/**
 * Get the day before today at 00:00 am.<br>
 * Means, if passed day = <b>Nov 5 13:04</b>, then returned date will be = <b>Nov 4 00:00</b> for days = 1
 * 
 * @param date
 * @param days Numner of days to reduce
 * @return
 */
public static Date getZeroDayBeforeDays(Date date, int days)
{
    Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
    yesterday.setTime(getDateMinusDays(date, days));
    yesterday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
    return yesterday.getTime();
}
```

**Finally, My questions:**

1. Is there a better way of converting the difference between two Dates to 'social' string format? As I said, I feel that some other way like maybe extending `DateFormat` object could be used, but I am not sure.
2. How to localize the strings like **'Yesterday'** and **'at'**, such that different `Local` set will change the strings to suitable language?

Sorry for such a long question, but I couldn't find shorter way to explain the need.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already one implemented library for that if you don't want to re invent wheel

See [`PrettyTime`](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/), with localization support

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
//prints: “right now”

System.out.println(p.format(new Date(1000*60*10)));
//prints: “10 minutes from now”
```

Comment: Very interesting.., it seems like it's what I looked for. I will check this  library. Thanks!